# a version of Poincaré recurrence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory

I've been trying to prove the following version of Poincaré recurrence with a
weaker hypothesis (finite additivity in place of countable additivity for the
measure) and with a stronger conclusion (a bound on the return time).
here is the problem:

> Let $(X,\mathcal{B}, μ, T)$ be a measure-preserving system with $μ$ only assumed to
>   be a finitely additive measure, and let $A ∈ \mathcal{B}$ have $μ(A)> 0$.
>   Show that there is some positive $n \leq \frac{1}{\mu(A)}$
>   for which $μ(A ∩ T^{-n}A) > 0$.

I think I could prove this, but I have some questions.
Here is my proof:

> At first, I used this lemma:
>   **Lemma** Suppose $D$ is an algebra of subsets of $X$, $\mu$ is a finitely additive measure on $D$, $A_1,\dots,A_n\in D$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(A_j)>\mu(X)$. Then there exist $j,k$ with $j\ne k$ such that $\mu(A_j\cap A_k)>0$.
>   **Proof** :  If $\mu(A_j\cap A_k)=0$ for all $j\ne k$ then additivity shows that $\mu(\bigcup A_j)>\mu(X)$, contradiction.

Say $T:X\to X$ is measurable if $T^{-1}(A)\in D$ for every $A\in D$. The result we're calling Poincare recurrence follows easily:

> **Cor** Suppose $D$ is an algebra of subsets of $X$ and $\mu$ is a finitely additive measure on $D$ with $\mu(X)<\infty$. Suppose $T:X\to X$ is measurable and measure-preserving. If $A\in D$ and $\mu(A)>0$ there exists $n\ge 1$ with $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}(A))>0$.
>   **proof**: If on the other hand $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)=0$ for every $n\ge0$ then I want to see that $\mu(T^{-n}(A)\cap T^{-m}(A))=0$ for all $n\ne m$; hence the corollary follows from the lemma.

My questions :

> 1 - How can I conclude this in the proof of **Cor** :
>   If $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)=0$ for every $n\ge 0$ then $\mu(T^{-n}(A)\cap T^{-m}(A))=0$ for all $n\neq m$
>
> 2- Does this proof really work? I mean Does the **Cor** provide all hypothises of **lemma** ? For example, $A_1,\dots,A_n\in D$ and $\sum_{j=1}^n\mu(A_j)>\mu(X)$.
>
> 3-In the main question I have to show that $ n \leq \frac{1}{\mu(A)}$, How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Note that if $\mu(A\cap T^{-n}A)=0$ for all $n\le 1/\mu(A)$, then also
>   $$
> \mu(T^{-m}A\cap T^{-n}A)=\mu(T^{-m}(A\cap T^{-n+m}A))=\mu(A\cap T^{-n+m}A)=0
> $$
>   whenever $m<n\le1/\mu(A)$ (because $\mu$ is invariant). Therefore,
>   $$
> \mu\left(\bigcup_{n\le1/\mu(A)}T^{-n}A\right)=\sum_{n\le1/\mu(A)}\mu(T^{-n}A)=\sum_{n\le1/\mu(A)}\mu(A)>1,
> $$
>   again because $\mu$ is invariant
>   (we are also including $n=0$ and thus why the sum is larger than $1$). This  contradiction gives the claim.

A minor comment is that "with a stronger conclusion (a bound on the return time)" is not correct since the same holds in the usual recurrence theorem (and nothing changes in the former argument).

Comment: Would you mind giving me a counterexample with $ n \leq \frac{1}{\mu(A)}$ ?

Comment: Sorry, in the beginning I was forgetting $0$. Since it is also there, the statement is correct. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, but the last question. What is the contradiction? Shall I take the space a probabiliy space ? I didn't see this in the main question.

Comment: And why is the sum larger than 1 ???

Comment: Because you sum more than $1/\mu(A)$ times (it need not be an integer).

Comment: PS: That's why it is irrelevant whether it is $1/\mu(A)$ or something like $k+1/\mu(A)$ for some $k$.